# Listing nested dictionary with list inside

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, nested-lists

I have this dictionary

```
dictionary = {
    "Name": "Eva",
    "Surname": "Schwartz",
    "babies": [
        {
            "Name": "Klara",
            "age": 6
        },
        {
            "Name": "Nikola",
            "age": 8
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get the babies names in a list. I tried everything, searching web for ages. Could anybody help please?

Comment: "I tried everything" - what _have_ you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: First I wanna say that im a absolutely beginner. So I tried for example this: print([x['babies']['name'] for x in d])

Answer (score 2):

You could use a **[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**:

```
>>> dictionary = {
...     "Name": "Eva",
...     "Surname": "Schwartz",
...     "babies": [
...         {
...             "Name": "Klara",
...             "age": 6
...         },
...         {
...             "Name": "Nikola",
...             "age": 8
...         }
...     ]
... }
>>> baby_names = [baby["Name"] for baby in dictionary["babies"]]
>>> baby_names
['Klara', 'Nikola']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
baby_names = []
for baby in dictionary['babies']:
    baby_names.append(baby['Name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the babies list is pretty easy:
`dictionary["babies"]` would return the following list:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Klara",
    "age": 6
  },
  {
    "Name": "Nikola",
    "age": 8
  }
]
```

Next, you want to "map" each var in the list into a new var: for each baby, dont take the full description object, but just it's name. In some languages like javascript, `.map()` is the way to go (for each element in the list, cast it to a new element. Or - for each baby in the list, take it's name).
In python, the better way to do list or dict mapping is using list/dict comprehension (you could use the same technique as in js and iterate over the list manually and take the name for each element but it's less efficient and common in python).

A code using comprehension would be:

```
babies = dictionary["babies"]
names = [baby["Name"] for baby in babies]
```